# Comet featured JAX-RS client

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, comet, resteasy

I'm developing a JAX-RS client with RESTeasy 3.0.6. One of the requirements to the client is support of Comet implemented with XMLHttpRequest long polling. I've been wondering how to feature a JAX-RS client with XMLHttpRequest long polling on the Web but all examples and articles I've found consider a client implemented in JavaScript. Is somewhere any documentation, examples, articles, etc. describing how to implement a Comet featured JAX-RS client?

Comment: What kind of Coment request and response should such a client be able to make?

Comment: @Lutz Horn XMLHttpRequest long polling. I've updated the question accordingly.